# Problema inciante em C

Tags: c

Estou com problemas para a saída de código, eu venho do Python e estou meio perdido na linguagem C, o que acontece é o seguinte:  Executo o código porém ele simplesmente ignora a entrada da variável condição, ele não deixa o usuário ditar o valor , simplesmente pula e cai no "Digite para ver os números pares "...
Eu já tentei muito e não consigo resolver, continuarei enquanto aguardo uma dica.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int quant;

    char decisao = 's';

    while(decisao){
        printf("Digite até onde deseja ver pares : ");
        scanf("%d",&quant);

        for(int num = 0; num < quant ; num = num + 2)   {
            printf("%d\n",num);
        }
        printf("DESEJA CONTINUARR ?\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%c",&decisao);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `scanf` está lendo o enter que você pressionou ao digitar um número.

Para ignorar os espaços em branco, use um espaço antes do %c.

`scanf(" %c",&decisao);`

Comment: Agradeço ajuda Vinicius, funcionou perfeitamente :)